# Почему AndroidStudio постоянно меняет JDK_1_7 на JDK_1_8 и обратно?

Tags: android, android-studio, java

Коротко о системе:

```
Ubuntu 18.04
Android Studio 3.3.1
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5264788, built on January 29, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-45-generic
```

Проблема:
Каждый день(или при каждом запуске студии, не нашел зависимости), студия в файле misc.xml самостоятельно заменять languageLevel с JDK_1_7 на JDK_1_8 и обратно. 
Дело в том, что я не вношу директорию .idea/ в игнор лист Git'a, и я вижу, что постоянно студия самовольно меняет уровень языка.
**В чем причина? И как с этим бороться?**

p.s. А каково ваше мнение, стоит ли игнорировать директорию .idea? И если да, то почему?
p.s.s. Заранее не знаю, нужна ли еще какая-либо информация.

p.s.s.s. фрагмент файла:

```
<component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_7" project-jdk-name="1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Потенциальное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32878888/android-idea-misc-xmls-languagelevel-tag-keeps-changing-jdks)

После долго поиска, наткнулся на данный вопрос, где советуют следующие два решения:

1. Добавить этот файл в .gitignore
2. Вставить следующий код в build.gradle и провести ручную синхронизацию:

   ```
   `android {
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
   }`
   ```

   Не знаю, можно ли считать первый вариант хорошей идеей, поэтому воспользовался вторым.